# Pdfminer, can not read LTText after pyinstaller

Tags: python-3.x, pyinstaller, pdfminer

I make an app that can read PDF using pdfminer. 
[image]

Application is OK when development.
After that, I package to .exe file using pyinstaller. But read result is not the same with it in development.

In detail, it can not read ***LTText* **LTTextBoxHorizontal** so I can not get extracted text.

Any one know about this issue, please help me.

Logs in development
[image: Logs in development]

Logs after I do pyinstaller

[image: Logs after I do pyinstaller]

> ```
> Python 3.9.1
> Pyinstaller 4.2
> pdfminer.six==20201018
> six==1.15.0
> Command: pyinstaller --onefile file.py
> ```

Related source:

```
 for index, page in pdf_object:
            # TODO: Only read last page - maybe change if PDF file change
            if index == number_of_page - 1:
                # read the page into a layout object
                self.interpreter.process_page(page)
                layout = self.device.get_result()
                print("Size of this page (%d, %d)" % (layout.x1, layout.y1))
                print("len = %d" % len(layout._objs))
                self.parse_obj(layout._objs)


def parse_obj(self, lt_objs):
    # loop over the object list
    print("Go loop")
    print(lt_objs)
    i = 0
    for obj in lt_objs:
        i += 1
        print("In loop %d" % i)
```

Comment: I open issues to relate library holder. Anyone can keep track issues at
https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5509 
and
https://github.com/pdfminer/pdfminer.six/issues/575

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pyinstaller lib owner just answered me. It fixed by adding  --additional-hooks-dir.

Please see [here](https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/issues/5509) for detail.

Maybe they will fix in pyinstaller to support pdfminer also in next release.